# Maximizing multinomial distribution with constraints using Lagrange multipliers

Tags: solution-verification, lagrange-multiplier, multinomial-coefficients

> Use methods of Lagrange multipliers to maximize $$W (N_{1}, \dots, N_{M}) = \frac{N!}{\prod_{j=1}^{M} N_{j}!}$$ under the constraints $\sum N_{j} = N =$ constant, $\sum E_{j} N_{j} = \mathcal{E} =$ constant. Assume $N_{j}$'s are continuous and $N$ large enough to use Stirling's approximation.

After turning the problem into the maximization of $$\ln W = N \ln N - N - \sum (N_{j} \ln N_{j} - N_{j}),$$ I proceeded to setting up equations with Lagrange multipliers $\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2}$
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial N_{i}} \left[{\ln W - \lambda_{1} ({\sum N_{j} - N}) - \lambda_{2} ({\sum E_{j} N_{j} - \mathcal{E}}}) \right] = 0 .
$$

However, I encountered a problem when calculating the partial derivative of $\ln W$:
\begin{align*}
 \frac{\partial}{\partial N_{i}} \ln W &= \frac{\partial}{\partial N_{i}} \left[ N \ln N - N - \sum ({ N_{j} \ln N_{j} - N_{j}}) \right] \\
 &= \frac{\partial}{\partial N_{i}} ({N \ln N - N}) - \frac{\partial}{\partial N_{i}} \sum ({ N_{j} \ln N_{j} - N_{j}}) & (N \textrm{ constant}) \\
 &= 0 - ({\ln N_{i} + N_{i} \cdot \frac{1}{N_{i}} - 1}) \\
 &= - \ln N_{i}
\end{align*}
Here, I imposed the constraint that $N$ is constant. However, it occurred to me that, depending on when the constraint is used, there can be different results:
\begin{align*}
 \frac{\partial}{\partial N_{i}} \ln W &= \frac{\partial}{\partial N_{i}} \left[N \ln N - N - {\sum ( N_{j} \ln N_{j} - N_{j}) }\right] \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial N_{i}} [N \ln N - N - \sum N_{j} \ln N_{j} + \sum N_{j}] \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial N_{i}} [N \ln N - N - \sum N_{j} \ln N_{j} + N] \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial N_{i}} (N \ln N) - \frac{\partial}{\partial N} \sum N_{j} \ln N_{j} \\
 &= 0 - ({\ln N_{j} + N_{j} \cdot \frac{1}{N_{j}}}) \\
 &= - \ln N_{j} - 1
\end{align*}
or (treating $N = \sum N_{j}$ as a function of $N_{j}$'s)
\begin{align*}
 \frac{\partial}{\partial N_{i}} \ln W &= \frac{\partial}{\partial N_{i}} \left[N \ln N - N - {\sum N_{j} (\ln N_{j} - N_{j}) }\right] \\
 &= \frac{\partial}{\partial N_{i}} ({N \ln N - N}) - \frac{\partial}{\partial N_{i}} {\sum ( N_{j} \ln N_{j} - N_{j}}) \\
 &= {\frac{\partial}{\partial N_{i}} ({\sum N_{j} \ln \sum N_{j} - \sum N_{j}}}) - ({\ln N_{j} + N_{j} \cdot \frac{1}{N_{j}} - 1}) \\
 &= \ln \sum N_{j} + \sum N_{i} \cdot \frac{1}{\sum N_{j}} - 1 - ({\ln N_{j} + N_{j} \cdot \frac{1}{N_{j}} - 1}) \\
 &= \ln \sum N_{j} - \ln N_{j}
\end{align*}
When should I use the constraint $N = \sum N_{j} =$ constant?

Answer (score 1):

Maximization actually does come from the expression :

$$ d(\ln(W))=0 $$
Giving

Lagrange multiplier on :

$$ \mathcal{L}(W,\lambda_1,\lambda_2)=\ln(W)-\lambda_1(\sum N_j-N)-\lambda_2(\sum e_iN_j-\epsilon)$$

$$d\mathcal{L}=0$$

Factorize by $dN_i$ in the sum, the factors (coordinates of the $dN_i$ in the sum is  null because $dN_i$ is a differential)

You will get the result.

Comment: That was the equation I set up. My question is: when taking the derivative of $\ln W$ with respect to $N_{i}$, do we treat $N$ as a constant or as a function of $N_{j}$?

Comment: $N$ and $\epsilon$ are constant here, i understand the ambiguity between the fixed quantity $N$ and the function $ N_f: (n_1,...) \to \sum n_i $ lets call it $N_f$ as a function :) And evertyhing becomes clear

Comment: Then, when taking the partial derivative of $\ln W$ with respect to $N_{i}$, the $N \ln N - N$ part just becomes $0$. Is that correct?

Comment: Nope. $N\ln(N)-N$ becomes $dN(\ln(N)+1)-dN$ as same as with a derivative :)